# Sending a file to a Django REST endpoint that has a FileField

Tags: django, api, rest, file-upload, filefield

I am sending data to an endpoint that requires a file in one of it's values. The data that I am sending :

[image]

The document's value is a file. But when I check the payload of the PATCH request in the network tab, the document is empty :

[image]

I have verified that I am sending the right data, but the payload doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: what response you have got from Django server?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu The format is incorrent, it is not a file. something like that.

Comment: I am not sure what you have got, but, the response might help you to investigate the issue further